# Deal with following dates in a table in R

Tags: r, date, matrix, row

My problem is easy to explain :

- I have one table with start dates and end dates and n rows ordered by "start date" (see image bellow - Yellow rows are the ones I want to have on one unique row with first start date and last end date)

[Table with rows where dates follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAN7f.png)

- I would like to regroup dates on one row when *start date n+1 == end date n*. Here is an exemple of what I need as a reslut (image below)

[Result i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvdW5.png)

I tried to use for loops that compare the two vectors of dates (vectors extracted from the columns) but it does not really work...

I tried something like this to identify start date and end date :

'''

```
a = sort(data$Date_debut)
b = sort(data$Date_fin)

for(i in 1:(length(a)-1)){
   for(j in 2:length(a)){
      datedeb = a[j-1]
      if(b[i]+1 == a[j]){
       while(b[i]+1 == a[j] ){
          datefin = b[i+1]
          i = i+1}
      
    }
 }
}
```

'''
datedeb = start date
datefin = end date

Thank you for your help, I am open to ideas / ways to deal with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. For each `Var1` group, create subgroups containing an index based on when the start date does not equal the previous row end date (keeping those rows together with the same index). Then you can `group_by` both the `Var1` and the index together, and use the `first` start date and `last` end date as your date ranges.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  mutate(i = cumsum(Start_date != lag(End_date, default = as.Date(-Inf)) + 1)) %>%
  group_by(i, .add = T) %>%
  summarise(Start_date = first(Start_date), End_date = last(End_date)) %>%
  select(-i)
```

**Output**

```
  Var1  Start_date End_date  
  <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A     2019-01-02 2019-04-09
2 A     2019-10-11 2019-10-11
3 B     2019-12-03 2019-12-20
4 C     2019-12-29 2019-12-31
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C"), Start_date = structure(c(17898, 
17962, 17993, 18180, 18233, 18259), class = "Date"), End_date = structure(c(17961, 
17992, 17995, 18180, 18250, 18261), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this is exactly what I need ! Explaination is very clear